# Removing strings from a list line by line

Tags: c#, string, list, concatenation

My question is, if I have a list that looks something like the following,

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("12345");
list.Add("Words");
list.Add("Are");
list.Add("Here");
list.Add("13264");
list.Add("More");
list.Add("Words");
list.Add("15654");
list.Add("Extra");
list.Add("Words");
```

And I want to be able to delete all the strings that start with numbers from the list and also concatenate the strings in between them so that it looks like the following,

**Words Are Here**
**More Words**
**Extra Words**

How does that logic look? Below is what I have been trying to do, but I can't first out how to delete the strings with number much less create a newline when i delete a string with numbers.

```
foreach (string s in list)
        {
            if (s.StartsWith("1"))
                s.Remove(0, s.Length);
            else
                String.Concat(s);
        }

        foreach (string p in list)
            Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("12345");
        list.Add("Words");
        list.Add("Are");
        list.Add("Here");
        list.Add("13264");
        list.Add("More");
        list.Add("Words");
        list.Add("15654");
        list.Add("Extra");
        list.Add("Words");      
        
        var resultStrings = new List<string>(); 
        
        string currentString = "";
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            if (s.StartsWith("1"))
            {               
                resultStrings.Add(currentString);
                currentString = "";
            }
            else
            {
                currentString += s + " ";
            }
        }
        resultStrings.Add(currentString);

        foreach (string p in resultStrings)
            Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

basically I am looping thou the list if the value is not starting with 1 I add the value to the `currentString`.
When the value does start with 1 we add the `currentString` to the `resultStrings` an start a new `currentString`.

There are some improvements possible, the if with starts withs 1 is not completely fool prove.
You could use `int.Parse`.
Is multiple items in a row start with 1 you can end up with empty string in the `resultStrings`
You could fix this bij checking is the string is empty before adding it to the list

Comment: This worked yes but can you explain the logic? I cant grasp how this is working

Comment: This is unique I didnt think about using another list and storing values in there. Thank you for answering and elaborating!

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing is "chunking" or "paging" your data, but you need to walk through each source element one by one to determine where your pages start and stop.

```
public static IEnumerable<ICollection<T>> ChunkBy<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    ICollection<T> currentChunk = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            if (currentChunk.Any())
            {
                yield return currentChunk;
                currentChunk = new List<T>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentChunk.Add(item); 
        }
    }

    if (currentChunk.Any())
    {
        yield return currentChunk;
    }
}
```

This is a reusable method (and you could add `this` to the start of the first parameter to make it an extension method) that takes advantage of [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=net-6.0#remarks) and [yield-ing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) results. In essence, you return a stream of values, where each value is a collection. So it's a *list of a list*, but with much more fluid terms.

What this does is

1. Start with an empty temporary list for the current "page" of items.
2. Loop through each element in your source.
3. For each element, decide if it's the start of a new page or not.

   - If it is a new block, return what you've saved up for the current chuck, assuming that saved chunk is not empty.
   - If it is not a new block, add the entry to the current chunk.
4. When you're done going through all the entries, send the final chunk, assuming it's not empty.

You can call this method like this:

```
var output = ChunkBy(list, x => char.IsNumber(x[0]))
    .Select(ch => string.Join(" ", ch));
        
foreach (var o in output)
    Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Which gives

```
Words Are Here
More Words
Extra Words
```

Comment: As typical for programmers, I'm bad at naming things, so if there's a better name for `ChunkBy` or `predicate`, I'm all for it.

Comment: This answer is probably better than mine, because it much more reusable and does not have some of the disadvantages of mine.

Comment: Im a junior programmer so all of this is a lot for me lol. I love it though! Can you explain what IEnumerable and ICollection are?

Comment: This is your introduction into the wide world of [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). Going over the interfaces it a bit too much for this post, but take a look at those links to get a start.

Comment: !!! great code !!!

Answer (score 2):

I grouped your words and then printed them like this.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        var list = new List<string>();
        // list.Add("Some");  <-- still works
        // list.Add("Words");
        list.Add("12345");
        list.Add("Words");
        list.Add("Are");
        list.Add("Here");
        list.Add("13264");
        list.Add("More");
        list.Add("Words");
        list.Add("15654");
        list.Add("Extra");
        list.Add("Words");
        // list.Add("1234566");  <-- still works

        var groups = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
        int gnum = 0;
        
        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            if (long.TryParse(item, out long val))
                groups.Add(++gnum, new List<string>());
            else
            {
                if (!groups.ContainsKey(gnum))
                    groups.Add(gnum, new List<string>());
                
                groups[gnum].Add(item);
            }

        }
        
        
       foreach (var kvp in groups)
       {   
           string result = string.Join(" ", kvp.Value);
           Console.WriteLine(result);
          
       }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("12345");
        list.Add("Words");
        list.Add("Are");
        list.Add("Here");
        list.Add("13264");
        list.Add("More");
        list.Add("Words");
        list.Add("15654");
        list.Add("Extra");
        list.Add("Words");


        var lines = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        var currentIndex = 0;

        foreach (var line in list.Where(x => x.Length > 0))
        {
            var firstChar = line.Substring(0, 1)
                .ToCharArray()
                .First();

            if (char.IsNumber(firstChar))
            {
                currentIndex++;
                continue;
            }

            lines.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(currentIndex, line));
        }

        foreach (var lineGroup in lines.GroupBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", lineGroup.Select(x => x.Value)));
        }
```

Comment: This also worked and seems a lot more complex to understand. Could you possibly break down what is happening with how you are using the key value pairs? Also how does             "x => x.Length >0" work?

Comment: .Where(x => x.Length > 0) is a linq query --> it loops only through the items of the list where is minimum one letter. if there is an empty listitem, the substring would fail. My code is grouping all the lines with an index. every time the loop reaches a number the index increments. at the and i have assigned for every line an index. for example the first items "Words", "Are" and "Here" having index 1, "More" and "Words" are having index 2. in the last step i group them by this index and join the groupitems